# Cordova Error: GET http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab/api/v1/cordova 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to follow this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRui-Ee-q_g&list=PLtKjv92L0ihAkTsq7-mxOGk8NrSXV7MY7&index=8

However, when I run `ionic lab` in terminal, and it brings up the browser, I get the following error in the browser console:

[image]

Clicking on the "lab.js:178" link at the right reveals where the error occurs in the lab.js file.

[image]

How do I get rid of this error? 
I've already reinstalled Cordova (`npm install -g cordova`), and it didn't change anything.

Should I manually edit the lab.js file so that it can find cordova?